# How to properly map data from multiple nested queries into desired object. React/Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map out my schema from Firebase Firestore. I used Flamelink as a headless CMS to make things easier, however I am facing a limitation.

The image storage location is separate from the data that i'm pulling in from my schema. To remedy this I created some nested Queries to find the correct path of the storage location and generate the URL for the image. I need that image URL to be placed back into the respected object somewhere.

Currently it's just adding it to the overall array not the objects already within it. The first console log is the file reference in the correct order, the second console log is the correct URL's I need into the original object. However, these seem to not be in the correct order. I am fairly new to react and ES6 so I could be over complicating things. Essentially I just want the output of the second Console.log into my ThumbnailURL position for each object in the respective place.

I have tried to just create a new Array of objects and map them in my front end, however that causes issues because they are not in the same object.

```
const storage = firebase.storage().ref('flamelink/media/sized/240/')

class ContentUpdates extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('fl_content').where('_fl_meta_.schema', '==', 'collateral');
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      collateral: [],
    }
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const collateral = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { name, image, thumbnail, thumbnailURL, img} = doc.data();
      collateral.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        name,
        image,
        img,
        thumbnail: image[0].id,
        thumbnailURL: firebase.firestore().collection(`fl_files`).where(`id`, '==', `${image[0].id}`).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const { file } = doc.data();
            console.log('this is in the correct order', `${file}`);
            storage.child(`${file}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              const fileurl = url
              console.log('this is the value I need mapped to thumbnailURL', fileurl)
              collateral.push({thumbnailURL: fileurl})
            })
          })
        })
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      collateral
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }
```

I want each objected in collateral to go through the necessary queries to return the fileurl back to it's respected collateral object.

UPDATE: I cleaned up the function a bit. Issue now is that it's going through two loops and not returning the values but only a promise. Very close to solving it however. Will update soon.

```
  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const collateral = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

      const { name, image, thumbnail, thumbnailURL, img} = doc.data();
      const thumbnailImg = this.getThumbnailUrl(image[0].id);

      let obj = {
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        name,
        image,
        img,
        thumbnail: image[0].id,
        thumbnailURL: thumbnailImg
      }
      collateral.push(obj);
    });
    this.setState({
      collateral
    });
  }

  async getThumbnailUrl(imgRef) {
    console.log('your in', imgRef)
    let snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection(`fl_files`).where(`id`, '==', imgRef).get();
    console.log(snapshot)
    let snapVal = snapshot.forEach( async(doc) => {
        const { file } = doc.data();
        console.log('this is in the correct order', `${file}`);
        let downloadURL = await storage.child(`${file}`).getDownloadURL()
        console.log('this is the value I need mapped to thumbnailURL', downloadURL)
        return downloadURL;
    })
    return snapVal;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }
```